# Regex in C# to detect a URL with angular brackets

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Could some one help me out by providing the regex to detect a pattern in C#?
The input string would be of the type-

```
<p><someURL></p>
```

I want to check whether the input has the content - <someURL> (with the angular bracket). So I need a regex to detect that

Comment: Please elaborate your qstn little more. What is your requirement ? and what code snippet have you tried so far to achieve it.

Comment: I want to check whether the input string has the content- <URL> Somehow that part got missed out from the qn!

Comment: Rule 1: don't use RegEx to parse HTML. Rule 2: if you still want to parse HTML with RegEx, see rule 1.  [RegEx can only match regular languages, and HTML is not a regular language](http://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/930393)

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the `<URL>` part between any `<p>`/`</p>` tags by using

```
var rxx = new Regex(@"</?p\b[^<]*>");
var reslt = rxx.Split("<p><someURL></p>")[1];
```

Output:

[image]

Mind that in case you have other tags, you will need to modify `</?p\b[^<]*>` regex. Also, if there are more tags, you will need to use `Match`:

```
rxx = new Regex(@"(?<=<p\b[^<]*>).*?(?=</p>)");
var reslt2 = rxx.Matches("<p><someURL></p><p><anotherURL></p>").Cast<Match>().ToList();
```

Output:

[image]

In case you have to deal with entire HTML/XML/SGML/ML and other .*ML texts, [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is the best way to go.

Comment: Please let me know if it works for you. If not, please provide more sample input data to test against.

Answer (score 0):

Regex Pattern :-

> \<(.*?)>

This will yield the groups of the text in between the angle brackets. And then in the foreach loop, you can retrieve the element text for the desired elements.

Sample - http://regexr.com/3aufj

OR

Use https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ to parse the html string into an object and navigate within the structure on the server side.